# Extract XML data and load into database (possible approaches)

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, ssis, xquery

My counterpart provided us a sample XML file and we are doing proof of concept whether the data in the file can be imported into a database.

The XML file is shown as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xmloutfile>
<header>
<TYPE>XLFT</TYPE>
<DN>C001</DN>
</header>
<table>
<row>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column></row>
<row>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column></row>
<row>
<column>ID</column>
<column>Title</column>
<column>Type</column>
<column>Country</column>
<column></column></row>
<row>
<column>12345</column>
<column>ABC</column>
<column>SN</column>
<column>Hong Kong</column>
<column></column></row>
<row>
<column>17777</column>
<column></column>
<column>MO</column>
<column>China</column>
<column></column></row>
<row>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column>
<column></column></row></table></xmloutfile>
```

What we are interested with is the values of **ID, Title, Type, Country (and perhaps a remark)**

```
<column>ID</column>
<column>Title</column>
<column>Type</column>
<column>Country</column>
<column></column></row>
<row>
<column>12345</column>
<column>ABC</column>
<column>SN</column>
<column>Hong Kong</column>
<column></column></row>
```

just imagine this is a general table, how could I insert those data accordingly?

Eventually I would like to do it using **SSIS** but at this moment (it would be good if I can do it via SSIS!), but just want to evaluate any feasible approaches.
Tks

Comment: In other words, you want to remove all empty rows/columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XQuery:

```
declare @x xml ='<xmloutfile>
  <header>
    <TYPE>XLFT</TYPE>
    <DN>C001</DN>
  </header>
  <table>
    <row>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
    </row>
    <row>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
    </row>
    <row>
      <column>ID</column>
      <column>Title</column>
      <column>Type</column>
      <column>Country</column>
      <column></column>
    </row>
    <row>
      <column>12345</column>
      <column>ABC</column>
      <column>SN</column>
      <column>Hong Kong</column>
      <column></column>
    </row>
    <row>
      <column>17777</column>
      <column></column>
      <column>MO</column>
      <column>China</column>
      <column></column>
    </row>
    <row>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
      <column></column>
    </row>
  </table>
</xmloutfile>'


select t.c.value('column[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , t.c.value('column[2]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , t.c.value('column[3]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , t.c.value('column[4]', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , t.c.value('column[5]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @x.nodes('//row') t(c)
```

Comment: Great tks!

I used : select t.c.value('column[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') ID
    , t.c.value('column[2]', 'nvarchar(max)') Title
    , t.c.value('column[3]', 'nvarchar(max)') Type
    , t.c.value('column[4]', 'nvarchar(max)') Country
    , t.c.value('column[5]', 'nvarchar(max)') Remark
from @XML.nodes('//row') t(c)
where c.value('./column[1]','varchar(max)') not in ( 'ID', '')